# Gradient descent algorithm in python giving lots of NANS

Tags: python, gradient-descent

I am new to machine learning and coding in general, so to really understand the concepts behind them I created a multiple linear regression model and optimized it with gradient descent  from scratch using python. but every time I run it, it (gradient descent) gives numbers that are too big or too small thus gives me Nans and even crashing. I've tried many things like doing a simple linear regression with gradient descent first. any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: the function that returns the slopes]

[image: the function that fits the data to the model]

Comment: Please post the code as text, not pictures.

Comment: print the output of SSR in each iteration, this is most probably the source of nan.

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.